# How to run a local and external website on same computer with 2 NIC's, 2 Routers and 3 separate networks?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Hello and hopefully I can get some answers to my question, though I think I'm making it more complicated for myself than it has to be.

My business is a used auto dealership, and I'm in the process of connecting it to the world - via ethernet from the business server [running Xubuntu] to the ISP's ethernet router/modem, so that I can host our own website (no more than 5-10 people probably visiting at any time - mainly paying their bill), as well as set up a web based internal-intranet site - via DD-WRT Router on the 2nd NIC on the business server - that'll be accessed over WiFi from employees personal devices. On the other end of this is trying to offer free WiFi to customers that is completely separate of the 2 mentioned above networks.

Quick Rundown:

1. Web Site for Customers to access.

   I'm going to use no-ip.org for DNS for the moment being, so I'll have a site that customers can access from anywhere in the world at "mybiz.no-ip.org". This will be forwarded to NIC #1 on the server, possibly at an address like "108.69.*.*" as its being provided an IP from the ISP's modem/router, that is from Time Warner, and they allow NO! configuration options.
2. Web Site for employees to access.
   I'm trying not to use the server too much as a desktop, only for critical situations, so having a back-end that's separate from the front-facing website is critical. This will be the DD-WRT router hard wired into NIC #2 on the server. This WiFi will be password accessible.
3. Public WiFi for customers.
   The DD-WRT can separate networks if I'm correct, I just can't seem to understand how to separate the 2 and still have internet access on both. I've done it before, but the "Public" WiFi (with no password set to connect) kept dropping the connection like a problem was happening that I couldn't figure out.

So, if I could do a little drawing, this is how it would/should possibly look:

```
ISP --> [Sends Public Facing IP of 108.69.*.1/8] --> ISP Modem Router

ISP Modem Router (Ethernet Only) --> [Gives Private IP 108.69.*.2] --> Server NIC #1

Server NIC #1 --> [Gives Private IP 108.69.*.3] --> DD-WRT Router

DD-WRT Router --> [DHCP Enabled Giving IP's 172.16.0.0/16] --> Employees Network
     |
     | ---------> [DHCP Enabled Giving IP's 192.168.1.0/24] --> Public WIFI
```

Hope it's not too confusing, but if anyone could give me some good direct tutorials on how to accomplish this, or if YOU know, then it'll be a lot of help. If you need any further information - don't hesitate to ask!

- Using The LAMP stack with Webmin/VirtualMin
- Customer site is located in /var/www2/
- Private Employees site is located in /var/www/
- Using no-ip.org's dynamic client updater

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions of this nature (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: @RickGreen: Why?. Specially why is this more fitted to Unix than to Ubuntu.

Comment: @CandN: Rick Green is not an AskUbuntu moderator. 2/3 of the actual close votes are "too localized", not "off-topic". I don't agree with them, but I can understand them. Your question looks too much like an attempt at getting free consulting than something that can be useful for others.